# Pass an Array of arbitrary arguments to a method invoked via reflection

Tags: java, scala, reflection

I need to create a function which creates a class from an arbitrary string and passes an array of parameters to a fixed method called "render".
The problem is that depending on the class the "render" method may take a varying amount of arguments. Unfortunately the "render" method cannot be changed to accept varargs so I'm wondering if I can still pass the arguments as an Array?

This yields: "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments"

Here's the code:

```
def perform(strClazz: String, pTypes: Array[Class[_]], params: Array[Object]) = {
  val clazz = MyClassLoader.loadClass(strClazz)
  val render = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("render", pTypes: _*)
  // params: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
  render.invoke(clazz, params)
}
```

And I call it via:

```
perform("MyClass",Array[Class[_]](classOf[String], classOf[String]),Array[Any]("first", "second"))
```

The invoked method takes two Strings as arguments so the following DOES work:

```
render.invoke(clazz, "first", "second")
```

Is it not possible to pass an Array then?

Comment: params.asInstanceOf[Array[Object]]:_* does the trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
scala> class Foo { def f(s: String, i: Int): Unit = () }
defined class Foo

scala> classOf[Foo].getDeclaredMethod("f", Array(classOf[String], classOf[Int]):_*)
res0: java.lang.reflect.Method = public void Foo.f(java.lang.String,int)
```